# How do i dynamically reference an object and its object and property in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm passing a property `options_r` into a function  but i need to reference to its properties dynamically...

to illustrate in a simple way, here's a function that takes in a parameter.

```
options_r = {}
function blah(myData,options_r) {
    output_data = myData[options_r.target]; //
    alert(output_data) 
}
```

THIS WORKS

```
myData.joe = 'male';
myData.anne = 'female';
let options_r.target = 'joe';
blah(myData, options_r);
```

THIS DOESNT

```
myData.dataset.joe = 'male';
myData.dataset.anne = 'female';
let options_r.target = 'dataset.joe';
blah(myData, options_r);
```

...and yes sometimes in need to reference an object within an object this way.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not `let options_r.target = 'joe'; blah(myData.dataset, options_r);`

Comment: `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` are equivalent, but `foo.bar.baz` and `foo['bar.baz']` aren’t. You would need to use `foo['bar']['baz']`, if you wanted to access those two “levels” in that same dynamic way. If you only have `bar.baz` in string form, then you will have to split that at the dot, and then move down the path in a recursive fashion.

Comment: @gaitat - i can't change or normalize the myData parameter, it's going to be dynamic

Comment: @CBroe  - yeh but i can't change anything inside the function, i can only play with the object_r.target  parameter :(

Comment: As the @Broe says so well: `myData['dataset.joe']` is different than `myDta.dataset.joe`. And obviously we don't need to have the `options_r` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to acomplish is not a native feature of JavaScript.

Some common extension libraries do that, for example [_.get function of lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get). Where in your case if you use this you will be able to do

```
_.get(myData, options_r.target);
```

Otherwise, you will have to code something that parse your path and does smart object traversal yourself.

The last option would be to use a solution based around `eval` but I really wouldn't advise going that route.